# Why is WebAssembly this slow as compared to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, performance, web, webassembly

Today I decided to play around with WebAssembly for the very first time. So, I wrote this little Fibonacci program in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int fib(int n) {
    if(n==0) {
        return 0;
    } else if(n==1) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
    }
}

int main() {
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 35; ++i) {
        sum += fib(i);
    }

    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double, std::milli> dur = t2 - t1;

    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
    std::cout << dur.count() << std::endl;
}
```

And compiled it into `Web Assembly` (WA from now onwards) using the following command:

```
emcc fib.cpp -s WASM=1 -o fib.html
```

Then, after loading the resulting `.html` file into the browser, the output I got was `14930351 592.8`, which means that WA took almost `600 milliseconds`.

Then, I wrote a JS equivalent of the same program, as follows:

```
export function fib(n) {
    return n === 0 ? 0 : (n === 1 ? 1 : fib(n-1) + fib(n-2));
}

export function fibSum(n) {
    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += fib(i)
    }

    return sum;
}
```

I used `performance.now()` to measure the elapsed time in milliseconds to calculate `fibSum(35)`, which gave an output of `347.200 milliseconds` on Chrome.

I get it that WA is very new hence the compiler must be missing some optimisations as compared to the V8 engine and it takes time to call WA code from the browser and everything but I was not expecting it to be this slow.

Thoughts? Have I not created a proper test case to compare the two?

Comment: Can you please remove all the `std::chrono` stuff and `std::cout` from your code and try again?

I made a .js file with the js code you provided and tested it and it took approximately 150ms when I tested it with (`node fibjs.js`). Then, I compiled the C code twice: once with the chrono stuff, once without. For the second version, I put the time-measuring code in the generated js file, before and after the `run` function. The first compiled version took 300+ms, but the second one took 130-150ms, so very close to the pure js code.

Comment: So...based on my results, I guess that using a lot of libraries or complex functions also affect the compiled js code.

Comment: @Adi Can you please guide me where to put that time-measuring code in generated `fib.js` file? I tried removing all the `chrono` stuff and putting time-measuring code in the `run(args)` method of the generated JS file but no difference.

Comment: At the end of the fib.js file, there is a call to the run function: `run();`; I analyzed the code and basically that is the entry point of the program. You can use a simple `console.time('test'); run(); console.timeEnd('test');`  to measure the time.

Comment: Rajat Saxena, did you manage to test the code? Were the results okay or it was just my machine that worked differently?

Comment: fib is just about the worst benchmark in existence. Burn it and test something else.

Comment: You're also not building with optimizations (`emcc -O3` or `-Os`).